# c++ can one turn a string value into a type?

Tags: c++, string, object, c++11

I am trying to write some generic code:

```
int _pID = _plant->getPlantInternalID();
std::string _plantName = getPlantBasedUponInternalID(_pID);
```

`_plantName` returns a string of the plant, like `Broccoli`

but is there a way to do something like this:

```
for (int f=0; f < _f.getPlants().size(); f++)
{        
    std::shared_ptr<Plant> sbas = _f.getPlants().at(f);

    std::shared_ptr<_plantName> sder2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<_plantName>(sbas);
}
```

notice I am putting in `_plantName` but really I need to do something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Broccoli> sder2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Broccoli>(sbas);
```

what is needing to do something like this called and how do I accomplish it?

UPDATE: I am just getting the ID based upon an internal ID I made up:

```
std::string HUDForStatus::getPlantBasedUponInternalID(int _id)
{
    switch (_id)
    {
        case 114: // Asparagus
            return ASPARAGUS::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 113: // Beets
            return BEETS::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 115: // Bok Choy
            return BOKCHOY::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 107: // Broccoli
            return BROCCOLI::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 101: // Carrot
            return CARROT::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 110: // Celery
            return CELERY::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 103: // Corn
            return CORN::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 116: // Eggplant
            return EGGPLANT::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        case 102: // Green Beans
            return GREENBEANS::plantName.c_str();
            break;
        ... <snip>...
}
```

}

Comment: So _plantName is a string and you want to get a type from it? How is `getPlantBasedUponInternalID` determining the string to return? I'd imagine that if you can get the type from the ID, then why don't you do that?

Comment: I made an update so you can see. So you are saying just make a function that returns the `shared_ptr` based upon the ID like I do for the string. I had not thought of that, simple I guess.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why you can't just work with a pointer of type Plant*?

Comment: BROCCOLI is actually a namespace where I store a bunch of constants that every object has when created.

Comment: If there were some magical way to do this, then whether or not `sder2->member` can compile would depend on the runtime string `_plantName`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the C++ way to solve the problem. Instead, give `Plant` an appropriate abstract interface and then you don't NEED to know which concrete type you're working with. Instead you just use the interface and let the virtual dispatch decide which plant it is and which implementation to call.

Answer (score 0):

c++ is statically typed language, and it is not possible to create variables of some random type at run-time. You could do it if your classes have a common interface, as shown in the example at the end.

To get a unique name of a type at run-time is easy with [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>

struct B
{
  virtual ~B(){}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct A1 : B
{
  virtual void foo()
  {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
  }
};
struct A2 : B
{
  virtual void foo()
  {
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<B> getFooCaller( const std::string v )
{
  if ( v==typeid(A1()).name() )
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<B>(new A1);
  }
  else if ( v==typeid(A2()).name() )
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<B>(new A2);
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc!=2)
  {
    std::cout << "pass type name" << std::endl;
  }

  auto b = getFooCaller(argv[1]);
  if (b)
  {
    b->foo();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "expecting  " << typeid(A2()).name() <<"  or  " << typeid(A2()).name() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say statically typed, not strongly types.

Comment: @DavidBrown I would say it is the same (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Static_type-checking)). Or,am I wrong?

Comment: your example is interesting but you didnt use `typeinfo` anywhere like the link to the article

Comment: @BЈовић - I didn;t need you to, just pointing out that you solution was different that your suggestion

Comment: @BЈовић Strong and weakly typed are ambiguous terms (as the wiki article you linked says).  Strongly typed does sometimes mean statically typed, but sometimes it means type safe. For example the python [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) says it is "strongly typed". So to avoid ambiguity I usually use statically or dynamically typed instead of strong or weak.

Comment: @Nevin I think it is. See [dcl.name]

Comment: this is turning out to be a good example, yet my question was down voted

Comment: trying to wrap my head around this more. Typeid. so given: std::shared_ptr<Plant> _plant` is it possible to do something like: `std::shared_ptr<typeid(_plant).name()> sder3 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<typeid(_plant).name()>(_plant);`

Comment: @Jason No, that is what is not possible. You can not use a string as a template argument. However, you can use an enum or integer. BTW take a look into [factory design pattern](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21268/factory-method-pattern-is-this-example-correct)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::shared_ptr<T> std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<U>& sp >
```

can only work when

```
dynamic_cast<T*>(sp.get())
```

would work. So in your case

```
std::shared_ptr<_plantName> sder2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<_plantName>(sbas);
```

conversion `Plant*` to `std::string` should be valid through `dynamic_cast`. For this to happen, `std::string` should be derived from Plant, and this means also that these types should be polymorphic (for this some virtual function is needed), because the `dynamic_cast` operator uses the runtime type information generated from polymorphic classes. But it is not possible.

solution:

1.
derive your classes from `Plant` - then conversion like

```
std::shared_ptr<Broccoli> sder2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Broccoli>(sbas);
```

will be possible. [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fkeyword_dynamic_cast.htm) might be of help.

2 . use abstract interface which `Plant` will implement. Then you will use methods from this interface to do dynamic type identification at runtime

Comment: ah, well Broccoli is a subclass of Plant. In the Plant Vector I store objects like Broccoli, Asparagus and they are derived from a base class Plant.

Comment: it has to be polymorphic type, for this some virtual function is needed